# Reusing json data to display a "detail" view on another html page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am creating a web page with a list of items (populated with JSON API http://vcld.fsdcmel.librarysolutions.com.au/VCLD_FS_TEST/SmartLibrary/Services/Search/SMLIB_SERVICE_SEARCH.asmx/GetRecommendList) in a table in the main page. When the user clicks on the item on the list, I want them to see a new page with detail list of the clicked item using the same JSON data

I'm thinking of storing data in a new object but not sure how to use that data to display new page

My code

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Recommended List</h1>        
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url ="http://vcld.fsdcmel.librarysolutions.com.au/VCLD_FS_TEST/SmartLibrary/Services/Search/SMLIB_SERVICE_SEARCH.asmx/GetRecommendList";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            // Reset table to blank
            $("#output").html("");
            var bookNum;
            for (var i=0; i<data.items.length; i++) {
                // result table
                $("#output").prepend(
                    "<p>"+data.items[i].title+"<p>"+
                    )
                $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
                    id = $(this).find("p")
                    console.log(id);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(errorMessage){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect use of either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` API. These allow you to persist data between page loads. You can find the relevant documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

It is a simple API.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); // sets 'key' = 'value'
localStorage.getItem('key'); // returns 'value'
localStorage.removeItem('key'); //clears key from storage
```

The `sessionStorage` API is the same (replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`);

1. So the workflow is to `setItem()` in click handler
2. Navigate to the next page
3. On the new page `getItem()` and use to build detail view

The object you will retain will need to be serialized because the storage cannot store objects natively.  So to store the data do:

```
JSON.stringify(myDataObject);
```

then when you retrieve it will need to parse it back into an object:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStoredData'));
```

Comment: Thank you for point me to the right direction!! Exactly what I'm after

Comment: @rsutti - glad to help. Please consider accepting my answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run one JS file for multiple pages.  Just include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

At the bottom of html pages like you would normally

Comment: The OP doesn't want to retrieve the same data - the intent is to create a detail view from the selected row. You answer does not accomplish that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Can he still use the same JS file and save the data into an object/array/variable and use it later on for other html pages? or localstorage/sessionstorage is necessary?

Comment: Normally we should only load JS that is relevant to the loaded page. But, the OP could use the same file - but it would be yucky :-)

Comment: I see, so basically load what you need to and keep the other JS for other pages separate.  Can he use separate JS files? I guess this would cause extra files to be downloaded as well, does not sound optimal

Comment: The OP's idea (I misunderstood your question above) is to select the data on the first page. With a page reload all the data is lost - we need some way to persist only the selected data. Then, when the new page is loaded, the persisted data is retrieved so a different view can be created. So page1.js has a job that is different from page2.js. They would not be loaded at the same time.